# Sobre menus em sites

Tags: css

Fiz um curso de HTML e CSS e agora estou botando o aprendizados em prática. Para isso, estou tentando montar um site, mas gostaria de fazer menus parecidos com o desse site "http://iswift.com.br/", em que ao passar o mouse encima do menu, faz um efeito bonito e tal. Só que como eu não tenho muita prática, não sei como fazer. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Olá Renan, bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Seria legal se a pergunta pudesse ser mais específica (dê uma olhada na nossa [help] para entender melhor como funciona o site, não é como um fórum). Você aprendeu sobre animações/transições via CSS nesse curso? É a base do efeito que você quer. Seria legal você tentar sozinho primeiro, e depois [edit] sua pergunta explicando o que já tentou. Obrigado.

Comment: Sugiro que você procure saber um pouco sobre isso: http://jquery.com/ E mais especificamente sobre isso: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_hover.asp Alguns exemplos que você inclusive pode usar:http://www.webmaster.pt/76-menu-jquery-14624.html Pergunta muito vaga, tente fazer algo e postar o que você fez.

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente cada item no menu é duplicado, onde o item de cima é o estado normal (fundo preto) e o inferior é o de hover (fundo branco). No hover do anchor do menu, o primeiro item cria uma margem negativa na parte superior, logo, ele sobe, desaparece, e o item abaixo fica visível. O fundo laranja é um hover do anchor ou do list-item mesmo.

Recomendo você ler sobre transições (css3) e inspecionar o código dos itens pra ver as coisas com mais detalhes.

Answer (score 0):

O que eu faria que seria mais fácil, é uma imagem em transição, 1 imagem que obtém os 2 tipos de cores das letras, branco e preto, fazendo um evento no "hover" da "div" ou de qualquer elemento que esteja usando para que a imagem vá para cima e para baixo. Segue um exemplo:

http://jsfiddle.net/hLs6v/

Mas no site citado, está usando 2 "span" personalizados que faz esse efeito... Mas com esse exemplo fica fácil você personalizar do seu jeito depois..

**Editado:**

Para explicar melhor o código feito, o que faz o evento ficar lentamente é o "transition-duration", então ao invés de colocar a imagem como background e colocar uma cor apenas, e no evento ul:hover colocar outra cor, as cores irão transitar de modo lento, dando o evento desejado!

Exemplo com apenas cor:
http://jsfiddle.net/hLs6v/1/